# Por que o Meta não altera a reputação?

Tags: debate

Por que quando recebemos votos positivos, negativos, respostas aceitas ou outras não altera nossa reputação no Stack Overflow? Já pensaram numa iniciativa de permitir isso? Ou de pelo menos, mostrar a reputação que você ganhou com o Meta?

Comment: Talvez [essa pergunta](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4788/votos-a-favor-e-votos-contra-no-meta-o-que-o-voto-significa-para-voc%c3%aa) ajude a elucidar sua dúvida.

Comment: Relacionado: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1871/28595

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## Pontuação separada

A pontuação do site principal dá uma ideia melhor da participação e contribuição do usuário ao site.

Se houvesse outra pontuação, o foco (que é o site principal) seria dividido e começaríamos a ter competição.

Eu não acho que competição deva ser incentivada aqui, pois iria distorcer o modo como interagimos e escrevemos nossas ideias.

## Pontuação vinculada

Votos no Meta não podem e nem devem significar a mesma coisa que votos no site principal.

Aqui é um lugar de discussão e não acho que deveríamos vincular a reputação de alguém a suas opiniões sobre o site, por exemplo. Caso contrário seria uma forma de inibir quem tem opiniões contrárias.

Aqui o usuário com menor menor nível técnico pode dizer algo que todos concordam. Da mesma forma um usuário de maior nível técnico pode dizer algo que todos discordam.

## Exceções

Hoje existem pequenas recompensas para quem faz edições ou participa da fila de análise. Não me lembro bem das regras exatas, mas é algo interessante que incentiva os novatos a participarem do site de forma mais completa.

Da mesma forma, *alguns tipos específicos* de perguntas e respostas no Meta até seriam interessantes de ter algum tipo de recompensa. Mas qual a natureza das recompensas ou quais os casos onde elas se aplicam precisaria de outro debate para definir.

Por exemplo, alguns pontos poderiam ser dados para quem encontra bugs ou quem responde à uma pergunta com pedido de suporte. Medalhas também.

Em contrapartida, para discussões e outros assuntos em geral isso não faz nenhum sentido.

Enfim, não totalmente contra isso, o problema para mim seria apenas complicar ainda mais o sistema de pontuação com essas nuances, mas aí vai da disponibilidade da equipe de desenvolvedores do Stack Overflow.