# Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português

Tags: debate, faq, destaque, perguntas, comunidade

[image: Um portão dando boas vindas ao jardim, mas pedindo para respeitar as regras]

Se chegou aqui, provavelmente teve sua pergunta fechada, negativada ou avaliada como tendo problemas e te indicaram este texto para orientação de como se dar bem aqui no Stack Overflow em Português.

**É importante** ler todo o texto para conseguir obter uma resposta adequada e participar de forma produtiva no site. Isso tudo pode parecer chato, mas é assim que se mantém a qualidade e agrega-se mais valor que maioria dos sites que tem por aí sobre **desenvolvimento de software**.

Se não vai ler e nem seguir os *links*, boa sorte! Só não reclame de as pessoas não ajudarem. Se você não se ajuda não espere isso de outras pessoas. O que pedimos é que você ajude as pessoas te ajudarem.

> Se mesmo assim insistir em não ler, nós preparamos o mesmo guia com uma versão [menos detalhada e mais curta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8089/guia-de-sobreviv%C3%AAncia-do-sopt-vers%C3%A3o-curta). Embora é mais rápido, o guia completo te ajudará a entender melhor os conceitos da comunidade e como se encaixar nela.

Pode ter havido um engano, mas quase sempre que a pessoa pensa assim, ela mesma que está equivocada. Se não concordar talvez precise ler de novo :) - estamos aqui para ajudar, mesmo que não o ache. Só não podemos dar uma solução frívola para resolver seu problema específico. Se é o que espera, este não é o site certo.

O SOpt é uma das ferramentas mais importantes de todo desenvolvedor nos últimos tempos. Todo **profissional** da área, com espírito de comunidade, tem a obrigação de entender o que ele é e como usá-lo de forma adequada. Invista um tempo para entender, será melhor para sua vida profissional.

Acredite, **adoramos iniciantes**, mas a pessoa precisa ter um pouco de noção do que faz e de comprometimento. É uma troca, você faz sua parte e nós fazemos a nossa. Não espere altruísmo se estiver sendo egoísta.

Se ninguém está ajudando de forma específica nem a tornar a pergunta melhor, provavelmente está muito mal elaborada e não vale o esforço de tentar salvar ou é desinteressante mesmo.

Não se esqueça, as pessoas estão aqui dando seu tempo e experiência pra ajudar **sem ganhar nada**! Em outras áreas você só obtém isso pagando caro (nossa área é das únicas que tem isso de graça, até movimentos sociais ganham dinheiro com seu trabalho). Motive as pessoas a se interessarem pelo seu problema, principalmente as pessoas que podem dar as melhores respostas.

## Não somos um fórum

O Stack Overflow em Português (SOpt) [**não é um fórum**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2068/101), menos ainda rede social (temos [outros locais para isso](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3825/101)). Somos [algo diferente do que você conhece](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7256/101) ([link um pouco defasado, mas útil](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/522/101)).

Isso implica em algumas coisas:

- Temos regras mais rígidas do que fóruns e redes sociais.
- Não fornecemos ajuda individual para problemas, fornecemos respostas para:
- **problemas específicos** e **bem definidos**,
- dúvidas teóricas e conceituais,
- problemas com ferramentas comuns **de programadores**, ao programar.
- Não damos "dicas", "luz", "ideia", "norte", informações sem muito critério ou mera indicação de material externo.
- Não fazemos discussões ou damos opiniões sobre algo. Se quiser, nós temos o [chat](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4739/como-ir-ao-chat), e lá é livre para discussões.
- Não podemos dar respostas oficiais que só podem ser algo próximo a um sim ou não ou que um *link* resolva (isso pode ser respondido em comentários, assim como várias outras coisas).
- Não resolvemos problemas que já foram resolvidos de alguma forma no site, mesmo que não exatamente igual ao seu, quanto menos específica é sua pergunta menos específica é a resposta e mais chance de ela já ter sido respondido de forma mais abstrata.
- Ao mesmo tempo que se a solução só ajuda a você, ela não é adequada para o site, já que a nossa premissa é ter soluções para várias pessoas, de modo que cada resposta deveria ajudar muitas pessoas e não só a você. Tente fazer com que a sua pergunta seja relevante para outras pessoas.
- Para ajudar muitas pessoas, a pergunta deve ser bem-feita em todos os sentidos, inclusive do português minimamente correto e bem formatado. Precisa também ser clara e específica (muitos não entendem o conceito e isso pode ser um problema).
- Não fazemos o serviço para você, por isso não coloque apenas enunciados, pior ainda se o enunciado nem for estruturado. Não precisa ser só enunciado de faculdade ou outro tipo de curso, até mesmo de trabalho que tem que fazer, **mostre o que tentou fazer, demonstre esforço**. As únicas perguntas que podem ser feitas nessa base são as absolutamente conceituais, e isso precisa estar claro na pergunta. Não importa se é simples, que é só uma expressão de *RegEx* por exemplo, se você fez nada não faremos para você. Não adianta colocar um trecho de código que você começou, mas não tem relação com o problema apresentado.
- Evite perguntar quando há erros de sintaxe, o erro que aparece costuma ser bem descritivo e você tem que conseguir se virar com ele. Se não consegue, provavelmente precisa voltar um pouco para trás e fazer algo mais simples.
- Quase tudo aqui segue um modelo de *wiki* e todos podem [ajudar melhorar o conteúdo](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2212/101). Só entenda que muitos usuários antigos já fizeram muito, ficou claro que era enxugar gelo e quase todos cansaram, então você que é sangue novo, faça sua parte.

Lembre-se de fazer **uma** pergunta por postagem. Em alguns casos pode ter mais de uma interrogação se o assunto for o mesmo e complementar e tiver uma continuidade, mas tente sempre fazer mais de uma postagem quando tem assuntos diferentes, apesar de relacionados.

Se a resposta exige quase um tutorial ou uma informação detalhada demais, ela provavelmente é ampla.Prefira ter um foco mais bem definido. Se tem que fazer boa parte do código necessário mesmo que tenha começado a fazer algo então ainda não está no ponto de perguntar.

[Vá fechando o escopo até a pergunta ser específica](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/488/101). Qualquer coisa pode ser perguntada se fizer do jeito certo. [Não tem perguntas simples demais](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4432/101), nem complicadas demais.

O ideal é que as pessoas cheguem em respostas do SOpt sem que precisem perguntar, assim, se tivermos perguntas bem-feitas, nos aproximamos da realidade. Pense bem antes de perguntar, veja se não tem outra alternativa. Somos um repositório de soluções formado através de boas perguntas, por isso não podemos aceitar perguntas ruins ou individuais.

Se sua pergunta tiver a frase "alguém me dá uma ajuda?" ou "alguém passou por isso?", ou "podem me indicar algo?", ou "me dá um exemplo", ou "ache o erro pra mim", ou qualquer variação disso, há 80% ou 90% de chance da sua pergunta não ser adequada ao SOpt porque ela não está clara. Faltam informações tais como:

- Tem o código, mas não o erro. Faltam detalhes como: a mensagem de erro, onde ocorre, em que circunstâncias, que dados foram entrados e a saída esperada, além da saída que ocorre
- Tem o erro, em alguns casos bem detalhados, mas não tem o código que o gerou; ou o código é amplo demais, ou seja, ele não segue o preceito do [**exemplo mínimo, completo e verificável**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (se a pessoa não tem todas as informações ou ela tem que analisar todo o código)
- Tem um código quase aleatório que não ajuda responder e apenas "enche linguiça"

Sem requisitos claros não dá para responder adequadamente. Se você não sabe onde quer chegar qualquer caminho serve e não estamos aqui para dar opções de caminhos, precisa ter uma resposta certa e que seja possível conferir isso. Entendemos que você no desespero está aceitando qualquer coisa, mas isso não produz a qualidade que queremos.

> Ao descrever o problema geral, você vai conseguir apenas uma resposta geral. Exemplo: "Como construir uma casa?", "Use blocos e cimento, construa paredes sólidas.". Em vez disso, pergunte algo específico e respondível de forma útil: "Como levantar uma parede usando esse tipo de bloco com tal inclinação e de tal altura de forma segura?", resposta: "Posicione os blocos no formato tal, execute esse algoritmo de colocação de blocos, não use essa ferramenta pois há o risco tal, aqui tem um exemplo funcionando de uma parede pronta para você ver como faz [link]". Vê? Perguntas muito amplas não ajudam.

De forma geral tem que ter uma pergunta. E ela precisa ser evidente, óbvia, de modo a que qualquer um a ler saiba o que está sendo perguntado. Você deve ajudar otimizar o tempo de quem está tentando te ajudar.

Se precisar de muitos comentários para concluir o que está acontecendo é um sinal óbvio que a pergunta não está clara ou ela é ampla demais.

Algumas pessoas não entendem porque a pergunta foi fechada como fora de escopo mesmo sendo de programação. Geralmente é porque está exigindo um esforço muito grande ou de não ter um problema específico. É comum que esse motivo seja usado porque está tão fraco que nem mesmo dá para dizer que não está claro ou é um assunto amplo demais.

Também é comum a pessoa questionar que a pergunta não é duplicata. Consideramos duplicata o que já foi respondido. Não precisa ser a mesma pergunta, mas uma ou mais respostas lá respondem o que está perguntando aqui. Não importa se a resposta é exata, só precisa responder, tem que te dar a ferramenta para resolver seu problema.

[Perguntas verdadeiras têm respostas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/507/101).

Se você discorda de tudo isso, talvez o SOpt não seja uma boa plataforma para você. Precisamos seguir a [teoria das janelas quebradas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/44/101).

## O tal do MCVE

MCVE é o **M**inimal **C**omplete **V**erifiable **E**xample, ou em português, Exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável. [Veja aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) como adotar o MCVE.

[Você precisa saber depurar código](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7785/101). Precisa conseguir [explicar o problema para um pato de borracha](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1186/101). Precisa saber isolar um código. Isolamento de código para fins de depuração, de entendimento, para explicar para alguém, para postar em uma pergunta e, mesmo para organizar um código normal, é algo que precisa ser praticado; é a tal da [responsabilidade única](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/100516/101). Se você não entende isso provavelmente está programando errado o tempo todo, mesmo que funcione. Programação não é só escrever ou copiar código de algum lugar, é organizar o código. Se você faz tudo aos poucos, uma responsabilidade de cada vez, fica mais fácil aprender e resolver problemas, sem falar em fazer perguntas aqui. **Dividir para conquistar**.

[image: Fiat 147 todo detonado andando pelas ruas]

Se você quebrar seu código em partes você aprenderá melhor, organizará melhor, achará o erro mais facilmente. Se você faz um bagunça, já tem um erro muito pior que o que gerou o outro erro, principalmente porque você acha que isso não é um erro.

Sim, somos chatos, mas é para o seu bem. A injeção pode ser dolorida, mas é pra você ficar mais forte. Não tome críticas das pessoas ao seu código ou pergunta como ofensa pessoal, as pessoas estão tentando te ajudar. Apenas animais irracionais detratam quem está tentando te ajudar.

Talvez a principal capacidade que deve ter é a de isolar o problema. Em muitos casos, fazendo isso você resolve o problema. Quando não, pelo menos poderá fazer uma boa pergunta.

Quando você posta tudo aqui e deixa para os outros se virarem pra te ajudar, está pedindo para ser negativado e até ter a pergunta fechada como ampla, não clara ou até como fora do escopo em alguns casos. Não é punição, é classificação de conteúdo ruim.

Se colocar o código inteiro, ele beira o fora de escopo, ou pelo menos fica amplo demais. Não nos obrigue ter que achar o problema no meio de tanta coisa.

E [não coloque o código como imagem](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5149/101) ou só fora do site. Imagens podem ser usadas para agregar uma informação que não pode ser colocada melhor na pergunta.

Colocar o código em algum IDE online é muito útil, ajuda fortemente sua pergunta poder ser respondida, mas só se for complementar e for um exemplo mínimo, completo e verificável. O código não precisa compilar se o problema for justamente esse, mas precisa dar uma indicação. O código em um IDE online pode ser mais completo que o postado na pergunta, que precisa ser mais conciso.

IDE's online: em JavaScript pode usar no site mesmo (tem ícone no editor para isso, e [só funciona para JavaScript, HTML e CSS](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2115/101)) para diversas linguagem tem o [ideone](https://ideone.com/) e o [repl.it](https://repl.it/). [Tem mais um monte em uma outra pergunta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5370/101). Tem até para banco de dados.

Veja outras perguntas bem formuladas para aprender como se faz. Só tome cuidado, no passado aceitávamos perguntas não tão boas porque haviam poucas assim, hoje precisamos ser mais rígidos porque vem muito coisa ruim. O fato de ter sido aceito no passado ou ser aceito em outro site da rede não quer dizer que sua pergunta deva ser aceita aqui.

## Título

O título bem feito ajuda as pessoas acharem uma solução para um problema igual ao seu. Por isso ele deve ser objetivo, relativamente curto e definir bem o problema de forma exclusiva. Não use títulos genéricos como "estou com dúvida", "erro na hora de gravar" ou coisas do tipo, também não faça a pergunta toda ali. Use um título único e identificável. Em muitos casos é melhor até criar um depois de ter feito toda a pergunta.

Em hipótese alguma coloque tudo em maiúsculo! Isso é desrespeitoso. O corpo das perguntas, similarmente, também não deve ser colocado em maiúsculo.

## Saber perguntar

Faça uma pergunta como um professor faz para alunos responderem uma prova. [Não coloque ruídos](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/38/112052), elimine [tudo o que não ajuda no problema](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/846/112052). Coloque tudo o que precisa. Se faltar informações, não tem como responder. Assim como em uma prova ou concurso você pode pedir eliminação de perguntas mal elaboradas, o fazemos aqui fechando-as. Você não gostaria de receber uma pergunta mal elaborada, então não faça uma pergunta assim. [Tenha empatia](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7651/101), se coloque no lugar de quem vai responder.

Se você não consegue fazer uma pergunta com tudo o que é necessário para alguém responder, provavelmente está fazendo uma pergunta que vai além da sua capacidade de programação no momento, está se esforçando menos que o necessário e/ou lhe faltam condições básicas que impedem você de progredir de verdade em programação.

Você pode estar com dificuldade para fazer um bom texto em uma boa pergunta. Se é iniciante, entendemos isso, mas iniciantes de verdade só estão lidando com problemas muito pequenos e bem restritos, além de serem fáceis. **Pessoas iniciantes em programação não fazem nada complexo.** Não vamos te considerar iniciante se você tem um problema complexo. E por favor não escreva que é iniciante ou qualquer informação irrelevante para o problema, mesmo se for verdade.

Se é iniciante e está fazendo algo simples, bem restrito, bem pontual, e não está conseguindo fazer um texto, então provavelmente lhe falta a base antes mesmo da programação. Volte algumas casas no jogo. Você não pode aprender algo complexo sem saber o básico.

Mais ou menos o mesmo vale para experientes. Se você não está conseguindo fazer um texto para algo mais complexo provavelmente está fazendo o que não é capaz ainda. Não tente aprender malabarismo quando nem consegue parar em pé ainda, **aprenda os fundamentos antes**. Casa sem alicerce não para em pé. Muitos dos fundamentos podem ser encontrados aqui. Se não encontrou, pergunte o conceito que está faltando.

Cuidado com o [problema XY](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/499/101). Não adianta você fazer uma ótima pergunta quando na verdade quer saber outra coisa.

Cuidado com as [perguntas subjetivas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/486/101).

Se não obteve uma resposta ou já tem uma pergunta igual, [coloque uma recompensa na sua pergunta ou de outra pessoa](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2079/101).

Temos uma FAQ de [**como NÃO fazer perguntas**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5483/101).

## Saber seguir instruções

Algumas pessoas têm problemas porque elas não entendem as instruções passadas, seja porque não leem com atenção, seja porque realmente não têm condição de entender. Isso se chama analfabetismo funcional. Não é para ofender, é apenas para dar um diagnóstico importante, até para que a pessoa entende que há um problema e precisa de uma solução. Analfabetos funcionais não conseguem programar, que é uma das atividades mais difíceis que um humano pode fazer. Resolva esse problema primeiro. Lamentamos e entendemos se ficar revoltado por ouvir isso, mas a situação só começará melhorar quando realizar isso e mudar a atitude.

É comum vermos aqui pessoas fantasiando sobre o que está acontecendo, supondo coisas irreais, especulando sobre o problema e tudo isso não ajuda a avançar. Debruce-se sobre fatos, faça uma análise criteriosa, detalhada e cuidadosa, principalmente antes de reclamar de algo, faça a reclamação correta, você não corrige um possível erro com outro erro.

Isso vale também para quem não consegue fazer pesquisas. É frequente a pessoa dizer que pesquisou e não achou nada. É igualmente frequente colocarmos as principais palavras da pergunta em um mecanismo de busca, ou no próprio site, e os primeiros resultados serem aquilo que ela precisa.

E siga os *links*, muitas vezes o detalhe que precisa para entender está nos *links*. A web brilha por causa dos *links*.

## Formatação

Já aprendeu Markdown? É fundamental para todo desenvolvedor de software. É ele que usamos aqui para formatar os textos e código. Temos até um [guia de estilo](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1084/101). Comece a ser profissional aprendendo e usando uma ferramenta tão importante. No começo pode usar o menu do editor para ajudar.

Formate seu código corretamente, todas as linhas precisam ter 4 espaços iniciais antes mesmo da indentação ou todo ele estar entre 3 crases (no início e no fim do código), isso também pode ser obtido no menu do editor (selecione todo o código e clique no ícone "{}"). Se não consegue fazer isso, esqueça programação. Escreva seu código com capricho, espaçamento horizontal e vertical coerente de acordo com a linguagem que usa e um estilo universal, torne o código fácil de ler. Falta de capricho indica amadorismo e falta de comprometimento com sua pergunta. Faça por merecer uma boa resposta de um profissional experiente.

Não amontoe todo o conteúdo. Use parágrafos, pontuação, respeite minimamente a gramática e ortografia. Não precisa ser perfeito, mas precisa ficar facilmente compreensível. Algumas pessoas vão considerar desrespeitoso um texto postado de qualquer jeito e mesmo que é uma criança semianalfabeta postando. Apenas crianças (de qualquer idade) querem o doce na hora, mesmo que isso lhes prejudique depois.

Lembrando que precisa ter pelo menos 13 anos para postar algo aqui. Se a pessoa não tem essa idade ou tem e não aprendeu o básico para formatar e formular uma boa pergunta provavelmente não está preparada para programar.

O que você faz aqui reflete no seu comportamento profissional e pode ser usado a seu favor ou contra, até mesmo em alguma contratação, faça do SOpt um adendo ao currículo, não uma mancha.

[Pratique aqui a formatação em Markdown](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/317/101).

## Tags

Use as *tags* corretamente. Com todas as necessárias e nada a mais do que é sobre seu problema. Classificará melhor sua pergunta e mostrará comprometimento, isso sempre ajuda receber uma resposta melhor. Os melhores profissionais que respondem aqui procuram por perguntas que seguem certos padrões.

[Não repita uma *tag* no título da pergunta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/297/101).

*Tags* possuem descrições sobre o assunto e *links* para conteúdo extra ou mesmo aqui do site. Muitas perguntas já foram respondidas antes e lá nas *tags* tem respostas canônicas sobre diversos assuntos, provavelmente tem algo ali que te ajuda. Alguns exemplos de *tags* que ajudam com um estudo inicial sobre o assunto e tem perguntas obrigatórias para aprender:

- [nullpointerexception](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nullpointerexception), [exceção](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exce%c3%a7%c3%a3o), [sql-injection](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-injection) (especialmente veja isto, é um problema muito sério da maioria dos sites), [pdo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pdo) (porque tem muita má informação no site e em toda internet), ...........

## Profissionalismo

Muitas pessoas estão se iludindo achando que estão programando só seguindo receita de bolo. Programar é **resolver problemas**, e o primeiro passo para resolver um problema é defini-lo muito bem. Pedir para outro resolver para você não é aprender a programar. Não tem como um problema ser bem resolvido sem uma boa definição. Escrever o problema ajuda na solução. Bons programadores começam fazer a pergunta aqui e, no meio do processo, acham a solução sozinhos, só porque tiveram que pensar melhor sobre ele. Se você apenas joga um texto qualquer está terceirizando o problema para outros, isso não dá certo e afunda sua carreira. Há um padrão salarial claro entre pessoas que não conseguem fazer perguntas e as que conseguem. Mude sua atitude se está tendo perguntas fechadas ou negativadas, fará bem ao seu bolso.

Descomprometimento é uma das coisas que mais afasta os bons profissionais e mais tende atrair respostas ruins de quem ainda é um pouco ingênuo em programação, o que pode te levar para um caminho ruim e estragar sua formação de forma indelével.

[image: Uma espécie de quebra-cabeças de letras de borracha onde enfia uma letra onde deveria caber outra]

Entenda que algumas pessoas querem responder qualquer coisa, porque acham que vão ganhar reputação ou porque só são bons samaritanos. Elas estão cheias de boa intenção, mas muitas vezes apenas estão dando gasolina para você ir mais rápido para o precipício que você já estava indo. Não confie na ajuda ingênua, pode te agradar, mas é como cocaína, dá prazer na hora e cobra um preço alto depois.

## Aceitação

[Procure aceitar a resposta que melhor respondeu a sua pergunta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/101). Não o faça se nenhuma respondeu bem, mas não esqueça de tomar uma decisão. Isso incentiva as pessoas responderem para você. Vote não só nisso, mas em tudo o que achar de bom no site. Classifica o conteúdo e ajuda outras pessoas, faz você [se tornar um membro mais efetivo da comunidade e dá um retorno para as pessoas que te ajudam](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/159/101). Se você começar ler o conteúdo já existente aqui aprenderá muita coisa, até mesmo os experientes sempre aprendem com respostas aqui.

[Já experimentou ver as perguntas classificadas por votos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions?tab=Votes) Dá para fazer o mesmo *[por tag](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php?tab=Votes)*.

## Votos

Não use o sistema de votação como se fosse uma curtida. Não vote porque algo é legal, curioso, divertido, e [muito menos porque você acha alguém bacana](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5132/101). O voto é importante, vale muito, ele diz que você atesta que o conteúdo tem **qualidade**, **está correto** e **é útil**. Se puder negativar tenha certeza que o conteúdo é problemático antes de votar, não negative por discordância e principalmente porque não gosta da pessoa, já que isso dá suspensão.

Não saia votando aleatoriamente. O sistema e as pessoas perceberão isso e você pode até ser punido, mas vote em tudo o que você vê de bom, [mostre que você se importa com a comunidade](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2632/101).

## Chat

Se tiver reputação suficiente, entre no [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11910/estouro-de-pilha) para pedir mais ajuda e tentar salvar sua pergunta. Esse é um local mais descontraído, comumente usado para tirar dúvidas sobre questões mais simples que podem ser fechadas no site, além de obter opiniões ou dicas. Você pode tirar dúvidas da comunidade diretamente a usuários mais experientes.

## Meta

Aqui é o meta, um site paralelo para dar suporte ao site principal. **[Não faça perguntas sobre programação aqui.](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6130/o-que-pode-ser-discutido-aqui-no-meta)** Venha aqui para discutir assuntos, pedir ajuda com o site, reportar problemas e participar da comunidade. Por isso aqui não tem reputação, os votos são mais por concordância e discordância e não para demonstrar qualidade do conteúdo. [A reputação do site é separada da que está no Meta.](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4854/por-qu%C3%AA-o-meta-n%C3%A3o-altera-a-reputa%C3%A7%C3%A3o)

## Não faça

Não se revolte porque não obteve o que quer, mesmo se por erro de outras pessoas (quase sempre o erro é seu, mesmo que ache que não), isso só piora as coisas. Não adianta culpar os outros, isso não te ajudará.

Um erro comum é apagar a pergunta, isso faz o sistema te suspender de fazer novas perguntas por um período cada vez maior. Melhore sua pergunta. Depois da primeira pergunta considerada ruim, comece a caprichar mais, porque vai ficando cada vez mais difícil salvar perguntas. Salvar perguntas ou mesmo respostas é a única forma de voltar ser confiável para o sistema.

Comunidade é assim. Qualidade se consegue assim. Se não quer fazer parte da comunidade e não deseja qualidade não tem muito o que fazer para você sobreviver aqui, [você se tornará um crítico do site porque ele não se adéqua ao que você espera](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8047/101). Aqui prezamos pelo profissionalismo.

## Conclusão

Queremos que tenha uma boa experiência, por isso faça a sua parte!

Você pode [ser um usuário mais dedicado no SOpt](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4329/101).

Aja profissionalmente, entenda que aqui é sua **equipe voluntária**, colabore com ela, ela vai te ajudar se você for um bom membro de equipe.

Você já viu o [tour](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/tour), certo? E sabe que existe a [Central de ajuda](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/help) para responder a maioria de as suas perguntas? Ainda temos a nossa [FAQ comunitária](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/699/101) (precisa de melhorias).

Se leu até aqui você tem potencial.

Pode ajudar:

- [Quais são as abreviações/gírias mais comuns usadas no Stack Overflow em Português?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6311/101)
- [Quais são todos os magic links que possuímos?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1616/101)
- [Saudações e Agradecimentos](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/846/101)
- [Como se portar ao perguntar/responder?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/38/101)
- [Contadores de histórias](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6937/101)
- [O que fazer com o "espero ter ajudado" no final das respostas?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5458/101)

E talvez a mais importante: [O problema dos Vampiros de Ajuda](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1160/101).

[Retorne para o índice da FAQ](/q/699)

Comment: O ideal seria os usuários mais experientes colocar o comentário enlatado [*linkado* aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8046/101) em perguntas que estão ruins, negativadas ou não, fechadas ou não. Assim mandamos uma mensagem para quem quer melhorar o conteúdo e não tem ideia alguma. Mostramos que queremos ajudá-lo, mas ele precisa fazer a parte dele. É possível usar um utilitário (veja mais lá na página do comentário enlatado) para facilitar a publicação deste e outros comentários prontos. Sempre cabe *feedback* mais específico.

Comment: Coloquei como wiki para que todos melhorem o conteúdo. Eu não acho que está bom, este é um começo, precisa de mais links, mais imagens, mais tópicos, resumir algumas coisas, melhorar o texto, a organização, formatação, enfim, dá pra tentar ajudar mais, cada um tem uma milhagem e enxerga algo diferente que o pessoal costuma errar.  Precisar resumir e retirar partes pra caber novo conteúdo.

Comment: Para diminuir o conteúdo (que pode assustar pelo tamanho), sugiro remover o parágrafo "Críticos", não o vejo como necessário aqui, mas não tenho certeza, por isso não editei. Também sugiro passar links de ferramentas de execução de código em outra pergunta, seja uma por resposta ou juntando as linguagens ou qualquer jeito, eles podem ser classificados dos melhores (mais opções, por exemplo) para os piores com os votos, mas também é só uma opinião

Comment: @Costamilam é uma boa sugestão. Na verdade estou pensando que alguns itens precisam virar *links* aí, assim o texto fica um pouco menor (não acho que deve torar quase tudo e virar um repositório de *links* úteis, mas podemos transferir algum conteúdo mais detalhado para outros lugares, mesmo que tenha que criar um *post* novo. Este é um deles que podem mesmo. Eu tentei juntar muita coisa que vejo muito o pessoal reclamando ultimamente. De fato já o comecei e deu mais espaço para edições no texto.

Comment: Fui colocar esta pergunta no índice do FAQ, mas não sei bem em qual das seções ela se encaixa melhor - talvez em "Sobre postagens em geral", ou "Moderação" - ou é melhor criar uma seção separada?

Comment: @hkotsubo coloquei em "perguntando" porque o objetivo é pegar o pessoal que pergunta que eu acho que é o maior problema. Podemos fazer algo pra outros tipos de participação, mas eles são bem menos críticos do que perguntas ruins. E não sei se vai ajudar muito, o grande problema de respostas ruins é a pessoa responder sobre o que não sabe e insistir no erro.

Comment: Já que vocês tocaram no assunto "tamanho de conteúdo", dependendo de quanto este post crescer, daria para fazer algo parecido com o [Manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%c3%83o-fazer-perguntas) e separar cada tópico em uma resposta. Assim daria até para aprofundar ainda mais em tópicos que estão curtos e os votos ainda servem de "termômetro" pra saber o que tem irritado mais a comunidade.

Comment: @fernandosavio a ideia dele é ser catalisador, um lugar pra pessoa ler o principal, o que pode fazer é ter aprofundamentos e resumir aqui, mas manter o geral.

Comment: Você diz manter todos os tópicos em sua versão resumida na pergunta e ter uma versão aprofundada como respostas?

Comment: Mais ou menos isso.

Comment: Eu ach oque precisamos incluir um "como fazer boas perguntas". Tem alguma coisa legal pra *linkarmos* em português? Tem algumas em inglês que podemos trazer para cá: https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/, https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/ e http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Comment: O último link tem a versão em português: http://clipart-library.com/perguntas.html

Comment: @CyberPotato não acho adequado juntar respostas aqui, ela foi pensada para pegar uma audiência que quase sempre é diferente da outra, dá até pra fazer uma guia para respostas, mas juntar as duas coisas não parece que ajuda, pelo contrário, coloca coisas pra ler que a pessoa que é o foco aqui não está interessada, eu eu reverteria essas edições.

Comment: Editei essa pergunta agregando informações de como responder também. Acredito que esse guia deveria ser destinado a instruir um usuário novo a lidar com as principais funções do site, e em vista disso, responder também é uma função essencial no qual precisa também de um "guia de sobrevivência".

Comment: @Maniero em vista disso, por que não criamos também um Guia para respostas, e brevemente, renomeamos este para "Guia de Sobreviência para Perguntas"?

Comment: @CypherPotato acho legal seu esforço, mas realmente a sua reversão me pareceu mais adequada nesse momento. Acho que é o caso de depois fazermos um levantamento do que tem de assuntos sobre resposta e ver se dá pra aproveitar algo. Nessa aqui já tem muita informação, e realmente o foco é o público que chega e acaba tendo a pergunta fechada. Raro alguém "começar respondendo", e nessa parte o sistema de votos ainda alcança.

Comment: @Bacco digo sobre respostas porque eu comecei respondendo aqui. Mas, em vista disso, em uma breve discussão no [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/52763658#52763658), fiquei em dúvida sobre estes guias mesmo. Será que criar um guia para "Como responder" iria realmente guiar alguém a como responder?

Comment: @CypherPotato seria mais questão de identificar se estamos com problemas nas respostas (problema que o sistema não tem solução). As perguntas estão um caos, a ponto de eu acreditar que não tem como consertar, só evitar piorar, e pra chegar nesse texto aí o Maniero deve ter perdido um tempo absurdo levantando e enumerando todos os problemas e links. Creio que pra fazer um guia de respostas precisa-se primeiro ver se é um problema que justifica, e depois entender a natureza de cada "subdivisão" dos problemas com resposta, e caçar documentação. Não acho que seja algo que dê pra fazer no susto.

Comment: @Maniero, posso editar a postagem para adicionar o link da versão curta no começo? Ou você acha desnecessário?

Comment: @LuizFelipe acho que não porque no fundo só da´para a pessoa entender nessa versão, a curta não é para entender, é quase uma pegadinha e pra mostrar que a falta de compromisso da pessoa leva a ela se dar mal.